# Extract string between 2 characters

Tags: sed, awk, grep

Say I have a string that looks like either of these:

```
nvidia-utils-beta 334.16-1
lib32-nvidia-utils-beta 334.16.1-2
```

I want to extract it so it would produce:

```
334.16
334.16.1
```

..respectively.

How?

**p.s.** I'd prefer a non-`cut|cut` solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when I saw "extract", grep came up first:

```
grep -Po '\S*(?=-\d+$)' file
```

or

```
grep -Po '\s\K[^-]*' file
```

test:

```
kent$  echo "nvidia-utils-beta 334.16-1
lib32-nvidia-utils-beta 334.16.1-2"|grep -Po '\S*(?=-\d+$)'
334.16
334.16.1

kent$  echo "nvidia-utils-beta 334.16-1
lib32-nvidia-utils-beta 334.16.1-2"|grep -Po '\s\K[^-]*'  
334.16
334.16.1
```

Comment: The `grep -Po '\s\K[^-]*'` seems like the most compact one so far.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some ways to do it with `awk`

```
awk '{split($NF,a,"-");print a[1]}' file
334.16
334.16.1
```

It takes the last field and split it with `-`, then print first part of split.

---

```
awk -F" |-" '{print $(NF-1)}' file
334.16
334.16.1
```

This divide all fields by space or `-`, then prints second last field.

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution using `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/.+\s(.+)-.+/\1/' file
```

For example:

```
echo "nvidia-utils-beta 334.16-1" | sed -r 's/.+\s(.+)-.+/\1/'
334.16


echo "nvidia-utils-beta 334.16.1-2" | sed -r 's/.+\s(.+)-.+/\1/'
334.16.1
```

Answer (score 2):

A `GNU awk` solution:

```
awk '{print gensub(/-[0-9]+/,"","g",$NF)}' file
```

```
$ cat file
nvidia-utils-beta 334.16-1
lib32-nvidia-utils-beta 334.16.1-2
```

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/-[0-9]+/,"","g",$NF)}' file 
334.16
334.16.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F '[ -]+' '{ print $(NF-1) }'
```

Using `grep`:

```
grep -o '\<[0-9.]\{2,\}'
```

Using `sed`:

```
sed -ne 's/.* \(\<[0-9.]\{2,\}\).*/\1/p'
```

Using `perl`:

```
perl -ne '/\b([0-9.]{2,})/ && print $1, "\n"'
```

Answer (score 2):

bash [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

```
while read -r package version; do
    echo "${version%%-*}"
done <<END
nvidia-utils-beta 334.16-1
lib32-nvidia-utils-beta 334.16.1-2
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk`:

```
awk '{print $2}' file | awk -F - '{print $1}
```

Comment: Its a working solution so I won't downvote, but you just made aho, weinberger and kernighan cry!

Comment: @jaypal, I will not vote it up for two awk commands solution. Vanda, anyway, good try.